# Python - get into all python dropdowns

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a code that does the following.

1. Enter the website
2. Log in
3. Click on a link
4. Click on a date
5. and select an item from the dropdown.

I wanted him to do this search in the first dropdown option that would be:

`wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_ddlVagasTerminalEmpresa"]/option[1]'))).click()`

And add it to my csv file and then do it in option 2 and option 3. How to do this?
Below is my code

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
import json
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep 




options = Options()
options.headless = False

dia = '{:0>2}'.format(input("Qual o dia do agendamento ? = "))

navegador = webdriver.Firefox(options = options)

wait = WebDriverWait(navegador, 30)

link = 'https://extranet.ecopatio.com.br/'
navegador.get(url = link)

inicio_str_dia = "a[title='"
final_str_dia = " de dezembro']"
diadoagenda = (inicio_str_dia+dia+final_str_dia)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_txtLogin"))).send_keys('*********')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_txtSenha"))).send_keys('*********')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_btnEnviar"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_TreeView2t8"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, diadoagenda))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_ddlVagasTerminalEmpresa"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_ddlVagasTerminalEmpresa"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_ddlVagasTerminalEmpresa"]/option[3]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="divScroll"]')))
sleep(3)
teste = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="divScroll"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')

soup = BeautifulSoup(teste, "html.parser")

Vagas = soup.find_all(title="Vaga disponível.")

temp=[]
for i in Vagas:
    on_click = i.get('onclick')
    temp.append(on_click)


texto = str(temp)

b = {'amp;': '', 'Cadastro': 'https://extranet.ecopatio.com.br/agendamento/Cadastro'}

for x,y in b.items():
    texto = texto.replace(x, y)

achado2 = texto.split('\'')[1::6]




#achado2_series = pd.Series(achado2)
df = pd.DataFrame(achado2)


df.to_csv('testa.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)```
````

Comment: The url is accessible neither from usual connection nor VPN. `ERR_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: You won't be able to, I'm in Brazil and I need a login.

Comment: It's difficult to contribute anyhow without seeing the actual website